# Blank content php code not parsing advanced custom fields gallery add-on

Tags: loop, advanced-custom-fields

I have blank contents where the content for the act gallery code is. I think there is an issue with the code.

```
<

?php
/*
Template Name: Images scroll
*/
?> 

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="wrapper" class="wrapper-scroll">
                      <div class="content">
                      <?php 

                      if (is_page_template( 'index.php' ) ) {

                        if (is_page( 'home' )) {
                      $jennifergallery='gallery_home';
                      };

                      if (is_page( 'people' )) {
                      $jennifergallery='gallery_people';
                      };

                      if (is_page( 'stories' )) {
                      $jennifergallery='gallery_stories';
                      };


                      };

$images = get_field('$jennifergallery');

if( $images ): ?>


<?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>

                <div class="section">
                <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

                </div>

                <?php endforeach; ?>


            <?php endif; ?> 
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And [this](http://www.redrocketwebsitedesign.co.uk/test/jenniferberrytest/) is the link to the wp test site. It is supposed to show some horizontally scrolling images. Here's the [link](http://redrocketwebsitedesign.co.uk/test/jenniferberrytesthtml/index.html) to the static test site.

Any help would be appreciated :-]

Comment: This is off-topic. See [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) what type of question you can ask here.

Answer (score 1):

1. The very first line contains an incomplete opening PHP tag, it should be `<?php` not `<    ?php` or some other variation.
2. Also if statements don't require a semi-colon after them. Your code is also not indented correctly. A good editor will auto-indent code for you automatically.
3. A good editor will also syntax check and point out errors as you type them. PHPStorm does this, Sublime Text has a package to enable it
4. `$images = get_field('$jennifergallery');` will not work. It will look for the field with the key '$jennifergallery', not the value of $jennifergallery. If you want to pass a variable into a function, just pass it in, you don't and shouldn't need to wrap it in quotes. `$images = get_field( $jennifergallery );`
5. `get_field` is an ACF function, not a WordPress function. If you're not using ACF, and don't have it installed and activated, this will fail.
6. You're getting a white screen because your PHP is configured to not show errors. Look in your PHP error log file, and it will tell you exactly what went wrong and where. It won't tell you why it went wrong, but it will tell you what caused it.
7. You have a lot of unnecessary PHP tags, e.g. `?><?php`, this does nothing, takes time to type out, and is pointless. Save yourself the hassle
8. `is_page_template( 'index.php' )` will never return true. You're not on `index.php`, you're on the image scroll template. I strongly recommend looking up the template hierarchy
9. It may also be that you don't have any images in the gallery. This is likely because `is_page_template('index.php)` is always false, so your variable is never set, so you never retrieve the gallery images, so they're never shown. When this happens, there is no `else` clause to print "no images were found"
10. You never give `$jennifergallery` an initial value. If you're not on the home people or stories pages, this variable will never have been created, it's like building a skyscraper penthouse before you've laid foundations, it's going to fall and crash out of the sky.
11. Would it not just make more sense to have a single field called 'gallery' rather than 3? That way you can grab the gallery field on any page and if it has images in it, display them. Now you don't need a custom page template!

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you :-] You've pointed out all the issues so I don't think I'll have any more problems fixing this. I don't think indents can break code, it just makes it a lot easier to read? I agree there's too many php tags, I pulled it straight from the act gallery tutorial and I din't want to break anything.

Comment: I used the [conditional tags page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) on the wordpress docs, where it said 'is_page_template( 'about.php' )', but I don't need to use that 'is page template' here as I'm already writing the code in the 'image scroll' template

Comment: A page template is not the same as a template. A page template is a template with a special comment at the top that lets you choose from a list on the edit page screen. Stuff like page.php and index.php are just theme templates and obey the template hierarchy

Comment: Indents can make whole classes of bugs very obvious, that normally get hidden by non-indented code. It's prevention + readability + courtesy all rolled into one

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you. I've now fixed that page. I called this template index.php as it is my homepage, but I guess that I'm using it on not just my home page so it doesn't matter what this is called. If I don't get sublime text or something similar I'll run it through a beautifier :-]